# Disable the delete confirmation dialog/message

Tags: 2013, delete, item, recycle-bin

When I delete an item or document from a list we get the "Are you sure you want to delete this item?" dialog. So it is not possible to directly delete an item, one has to confirm the deletion by clicking on "OK".

Is there a way to disable this dialog (globally)? Haven't found any settings for this also not inside the WebApps recycle bin settings (Recycle Bin is still required).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can not disable it. (afaik)
You can create a custom item action to delete the selected item and hide
the old delete button.